# How to get microphone input from both ears simultaniosly on Apple Airpods?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, headphones

Is it possible to do such thing ? I see in ios setting you can set one of 3 options for Airpods microphone:

1) Automatically Switch AirPods
2) Always Left Airpod 
3) Always Right Airpod

If it's not possible to read microphone input simultaneously from both ears can I switch microphone input from left or right earbud on Apple Airpods programmatically ?

Comment: You don't have access to AirPods API, it is managed by the system